# Problems understanding Redis ServiceStack Example

Tags: redis, servicestack

I am trying to get a grip on the ServiceStack Redis example and Redis itself and now have some questions.

Question 1:

I see some static indexes defined, eg:

```
static class TagIndex
{
    public static string Questions(string tag) { return "urn:tags>q:" + tag.ToLower(); }
    public static string All { get { return "urn:tags"; } }
}
```

What does that '>' (greater than) sign do? Is this some kind of convention?

Question 2:

```
public User GetOrCreateUser(User user)
{
    var userIdAliasKey = "id:User:DisplayName:" + user.DisplayName.ToLower();
    using (var redis = RedisManager.GetClient())
    {
        var redisUsers = redis.As<User>();

        var userKey = redis.GetValue(userIdAliasKey);
        if (userKey != null) return redisUsers.GetValue(userKey);

        if (user.Id == default(long)) user.Id = redisUsers.GetNextSequence();

        redisUsers.Store(user);
        redis.SetEntry(userIdAliasKey, user.CreateUrn());

        return redisUsers.GetById(user.Id);
    }
}
```

As far as I can understand, first a user is stored with a unique id. Is this necessary when using the client (I know this is not for Redis necessary)? I have for my model a meaningful string id (like an email address) which I like to use. I also see a SetEntry is done. What does SetEntry do exactly? I think it is an extra key just to set a relation between the id and a searchable key. I guess this is not necessary when storing the object itself with a meaningful key, so user.id = "urn:someusername". And how is SetEntry stored as a Redis Set or just an extra key?

Question 3:

This is more Redis related but I am trying to figure out how everything is stored in Redis in order to get a grip on the example so I did:

- Started redis-cli.exe in a console
- Typed 'keys *' this shows all keys
- Typed 'get id:User:DisplayName:joseph' this showed 'urn:user:1'
- Typed 'get urn:user:1' this shows the user

Now I also see keys like 'urn:user>q:1' or 'urn:tags' if I do a 'get urn:tags' I get the error 'ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value'. And tried other Redis commands like smembers but I cannot find the right query commands.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1: `return "urn:tags>q:" + tag.ToLower();` gives you the key (a string) for a given tag; the ">" has no meaning for Redis, it's a convention of the developer of the example, and could have been any other character.

Question 3: use the [TYPE](http://redis.io/commands/type) command to determine the type of the key, then you'll find the right command in redis documentation to get the values.

Comment: Many thanks! With your TYPE hint I could for example for 'type urn:tags' determine it is a zset. And 'zrange urn:tags 0 -1' showed the range.